# How to grep from within specified character range in line and then print entire line

Tags: awk, grep, cut

I have a file which have multiple row each row contains 3400 characters.  I want to grep something from specified character range, let's say I want to grep `"pavan"` between character range 14 to 25 in the line.

To do this I can simply do like below

```
cat filename | cut -c 14-25 | grep pavan
```

I tried to use awk command but it does not work since the lines have more than `3000 characters
but by this complete line will not print.

I want to print complete line also so that I can perform further operation on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v pattern="pavan" 'match( substr($0, 14, 11), pattern )' file
```

Will print the matching lines.

<strike>A more complicated way of doing the same thing:</strike>

```
awk -v patt="pavan" -v start=14 -v end=25 '
    match($0,patt) && start <= RSTART && RSTART <= end-RLENGTH
' file
```

-- stricken due to valid commentary from Ed Morton.

Comment: +1 for the first version in particular. For the 2nd, I find `start <= RSTART && (RSTART+RLENGTH) <= end` clearer but YMMV I suppose. You could add `match( substr($0, start, end-start), pattern )` for completeness if you like.

Comment: Oh, I just realised you shouldn't do the 2nd version because if the pattern that you're searching for exists in, say, the first 11 characters of the line AND in the 14-25th characters, then the match() will find it in the first 11 and set RSTART/RLENGTH accordingly and so your line will not get printed even though the pattern did exist in the desired line segment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant, but does work!

Start off with what you had, but remove the unnecessary `cat`:

```
cut -c 14-25 file
```

now get `awk` to find the string you want and print the line number:

```
cut -c 14-25 file | awk '/paven/{print NR}'
```

Now you have a list of all the line numbers that you want. You can either process them in a while loop, like this:

```
cut -c 14-25 file | awk '/pavan/{print NR}' | while read line; do
   echo $line
   sed -n "${line} p"
done
```

or put them in an array

```
lines=($(cut -c 14-25 file | awk '/pavan/{print NR}'))
echo ${lines[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some bit of *arithmetic* and you could use `grep`:

```
grep -E '^.{13}.{0,7}pavan' filename
```

This would match lines containing `pavan` between the specified character range.

It essentially matches 13 arbitrary characters at the beginning of a line.  Then looks for `pavan` that can be preceded by 0 to 7 arbitrary characters.